# Mappear con automapper propiedades anidadas

Tags: c#, automapper

Tengo las siguientes clases:

```
 public class Product
 {
     public int Id { get; set; }
     public string Name { get; set; }
     public string Description { get; set; }
     public ProductStatus Status { get; set; }
     public List<ProductPrice> Prices { get; set; }
     public List<ProductStock> Stocks { get; set; }
 }

public class ProductPrice
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public int ProductId { get; set; }        
    public decimal Price { get; set; }
    public DateTime StartDate { get; set; }
    public DateTime EndDate { get; set; }
}

 public class ProductWithPricesResponse
 {
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string Description { get; set; }
    public List<ProductPriceResponse> Prices { get; set; }
 }

public class ProductPriceResponse
{
    public decimal Price { get; set; }
    public DateTime StartDate { get; set; }
    public DateTime EndDate { get; set; }
}
```

Quiero mappear la clase de Product a la clase ProductWithPricesResponse usando Automapper, pero no se como realizar el mapeo anidado del listado de ProductPrices de la clase Product al listado de ProductPriceResponse de la clase ProductWithPricesResponse.

Trate de utilizar algo por el estilo en el profile:

```
    public ProductProfile(IMapper mapper)
    {
        _mapper = mapper;
        CreateMap<Product, ProductWithPricesResponse>()
            .ConvertUsing(x => x.Prices.Select(y => _mapper.Map<ProductPrice, ProductPriceResponse>(y)).ToList());
    }
```

Lo que quise hacer ahi fue, primero decirle que voy a mappear de Product a ProductWithPrices y que dentro del listado de Prices de Product, cada item lo convierta de ProductPrice a ProductPriceResponse, pero me da un error que no puedo implicitamente convertir de una lista generica de ProductPriceResponse a un objeto de ProductWithPricesResponse.

Alguien ya realizo algun tipo de anidacion con Automapper y me sepa explicar esto?

Answer (score 0):

Considerando que:

1. La pregunta está sin detalles de `ProductStatus`.
2. La pregunta está sin detalles de `ProductStock`.

Y si he entendido bien, el siguiente código soluciona tu caso:

```
CreateMap<Product, ProductWithPricesResponse>()
    .ForMember(dest => dest.Prices, opt => opt.MapFrom(src => src.Prices.Select(p => new ProductPriceResponse
    {
        Price = p.Price,
        StartDate = p.StartDate,
        EndDate = p.EndDate
    })));
```

Te sugiero revisar la documentación:

https://docs.automapper.org/en/stable/Mapping-inheritance.html